# Sane way to add members to a memder via anonymous subclass

Tags: scala

I'm learning Scala along with a DSL called [Chisel](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/).
In Chisel there is an omnipresent pattern like:

```
class TestModule extends Module {
  // overriding an io field of Module
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    // add a new field, that was not defined in Bundle
    val a = ...
  })
  // do something with io.a
}
```

As I figured out, this code can't be compiled ever since Scala 2.12.0 . Because of a [change](https://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0/#inferred-types-for-fields) in type inference, the `io` field does not get the 'extended' type, and `io.a` is not accessible effectively from anywhere outside the definition of the anonymous subclass.
I can understand (more or less) the motivation of this change.
But this very implication of it looks quite strange to me.

I've managed to write some ways to overcome this problem, but none of them satisfies me completely.

So:
What is the shortest way to extend an overridden-field-object with new fields?

- From a DSL-user point of view
- From a DSL(library)-writer point of view

And being more general: what is the best way to add fields 'in-place'? And if there is no good way, why is adding fields in-place is so much left out?

#### My solutions for DSL-users:

- add an explicit type definition, as supposed by the authors of the change

```
class TestModule extends Module {
  val io: {val a: Type; ...} = IO(new Bundle {
    val a = ...
    ...
  })
}
```

This kinda doubles the typing. With more than about three additional fields this looks really scary. Even being broken into multiple lines. And in Chisel there usually are quite a lot of fields here.

- assign the whole thing to another (non-overriding) field first

```
class TestModule extends Module {
  val myIo = IO(new Bundle {
    val a = ...
    ...
  })
  val io = myIo
}
```

Adds one unnecessary line, forces to invent another name... And looks like magic. Really.

- make the class named instead of anonymous

```
class TestModule extends Module {
  class MyIo extends Bundle {
    val a = ...
    ...
  }
  val io = IO(new MyIo)
}
```

Still a line and a name. And looks a bit too involved for people who came to use a DSL without much will to dive deep into Scala (I'm not one of them, but I know a lot of such people).

As for DSL-writers, I can suggest only to write a macro. And, as far as I understand the problem, the macro should not only be plugged in place of the IO() function, but it should replace the whole `val io = IO(...)` assignment.